# Thread and ThreadStart

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Both of the following lines work same. but is there any hidden difference? and which one should be preferred?

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(aMethod);

Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(aMethod));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Specifying a language tag may get this question more attention.  C#?

Comment: Check out this post [Why does new Thread() accept a method name, even though none of the constructor overloads seem to allow this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595582/why-does-new-thread-accept-a-method-name-even-though-none-of-the-constructor)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Delegate Instantiation vs. Just Passing the Method Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181282/c-sharp-delegate-instantiation-vs-just-passing-the-method-reference)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no difference. Both lines are equal.

Comment: I know there is no difference (tried it) but it would be desirable to support it with any additional links to documentation, references ...

Answer (score 6):

The c# compiler will transform the 
`Thread t1 = new Thread(aMethod);` 
statement to
`Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(aMethod));`

Answer (score 3):

They are just the same but the second one allows you to use an extra parameter at the Thread starting method (well using ParametrizedThreadStart instead of ThreadStart).

Answer (score 0):

A ThreadStart represents the method that executes on a Thread, so this is exactly the same thing.