# Why use "new DelegateType(Delegate)"?

Tags: c#, delegates

Ok, suppose you define a delegate in some class.

```
public delegate void StringDelegate (string s);
```

and another class implements a method :

```
public static void StringWriter (string s) {...}
```

In the book that I'm reading "Programming C#" 4th ed they create delegates using the **new** keyword, ex:

```
ClassDelegate.StringDelegate writer;
writer = new ClassDelegate.StringDelegate (DelegateImplementer.StringWriter);
writer("Hello");
```

However, I see one can also call the delegate method this way

```
ClassDelegate.StringDelegate writer;
writer = DelegateImplementer.StringWriter;
writer ("Hello");
```

What's the difference? Why do I want instantiate and create an object delegate when I can just simply pass or make reference to the signature of the method delegate.

Comment: I often use the former because that is what VS auto-completes to after a `+=` ;-) About the only other time I use named delegates is in parameters to function calls, in which case the latter is the much cleaner choice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Delegate Instantiation vs. Just Passing the Method Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181282/c-sharp-delegate-instantiation-vs-just-passing-the-method-reference)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference between the two statements.  `writer = DelegateImplementer.StringWriter;` still creates a `delegate` object; the compiler will generate the `new ClassDelegate.StringDelegate ()` for you.  It's just a cleaner syntax that was [added in C# 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173176%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

As @Ben Voigt mentioned in his answer is only required in C# 2.0 where the compiler can't deduce the type of the delegate, when using [Control.Invoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) for example.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the correct type can't be deduced (like when you're calling a generic), in such a case you need to let the compiler know what kind of delegate you want.

Most of the time, though, naming the method group is easier and clearer.

Answer (score 4):

The two are equivalent. The latter is syntax new with C# 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Both are the same, but the latter syntax was added in C#2 to simplify delegate usage.

Both methods compile to the same byte code.

Answer (score 1):

It's syntactic sugar.  Ultimately both sets of code do the same thing.

I'd also note that .Net has a bunch of generic delegates built in that can save you alot of coding.  In this case I'd do:

```
Action<string> writer;
writer = DelegateImplementer.StringWriter;
writer ("Hello");
```

This way you don't even need to create your own delegate.