# How to use the same thread function for multiple threads in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why use “new DelegateType(Delegate)”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735159/why-use-new-delegatetypedelegate)

Just wanted to know the difference between `Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadFunction));` and 
`Thread thread1 = new Thread(ThreadFunction);`? Any ideas please???

Edited:
When i invoke the same thread function using two threads then is the function is working as a copy for one thread or the both threads use the same function?

Comment: Only different syntax. Also you have `Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => ThreadFunction());` an `Action` invoking your ThreadFunction

Comment: Please any body answer the edited part of my question!
by the way, thanks @L.B for answering/clarifying the first part.

Comment: The behaviour of the two things listed is identical. Usually the important thing is: including a different state parameter for the thread's configuration / parameters

Comment: Please answer edited part of the question!!!

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, but the same function will execute with different local data.

Comment: @shujaat: Both threads use the same function.