# Differences with delegate declaration in c#

Tags: c#, delegates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why use “new DelegateType(Delegate)”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735159/why-use-new-delegatetypedelegate)
>   [What is the difference between new Thread(void Target()) and new Thread(new ThreadStart(void Target()))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482121/what-is-the-difference-between-new-threadvoid-target-and-new-threadnew-thre)

So I have been through a little bit of delegate and got the whole idea somehow. 
Now, I see everywhere exemple like this:

```
public delegate void Deleg();
Deleg deleg = new Deleg(FunctionName);

deleg();
```

I would think this creates an delegate object with the function to point at being passed as parameter to the constructor.

Now, I can also do like this:

```
public delegate void Deleg();
public Deleg deleg;  

deleg = FunctionName;
deleg();
```

This one seems to only create a reference and the address of the function is passed. This works just the same and has all the delegate functionalities.

But now, regardless of the fact I have one more line in the second exemple, do I actually lose or gain something out of the second since the first one is more popular on tutorials?

Comment: Yep, my bad that is an actual duplicate. Should I remove the question?

Comment: You can't remove it anymore. Just lat the voting take its course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gain is a little less typing. The compiler is smarter now than it was initially, so it can do the method group conversion implicitly which is why you don't have to do `new Deleg(FunctionName)` anymore.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, I was asking as I do not have the visual studio command prompt on this computer to look at the IL.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the assignment on the same line (as you do in the first examaple), then the amount of code you type is about the same.

```
public delegate void Deleg();
public Deleg deleg = FunctionName;
deleg();
```

Answer (score 0):

Second is delegate inference.

Does the method match with delegate's input parameter list in order and type?

- **Yes** -> The delegate is inferred because the method signature matches the delegate's one.
- **No** -> The delegate and method input parameters doesn't match. No delegate type inference is possible.

Do you lose something using delegate type inference? **No**. It's the same thing and I would argue that's preferable: less verbose code and it improves readability.

In addition, delegate type inference adds another option for you:

```
public delegate void Do();

Do some = () =>
{
   // Do stuff
};
```

Or

```
public delegate void Do(string a, string b);

// C# compiler infers the delegate from the lambda/anonymous method signature and it infers the type of the whole parameters too!
Do some = (a, b) =>
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Actually this has nothing to do with type inference.

Comment: @HenkHotlerman After all, a delegate is a type. This is why I said _delegate type inference_ instead of just _type inference_.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've edited that... Now you find _delegate inference_ everywhere. Anyway, I believe it wasn't incorrect at all.