# C# delegate instantiation syntax

Tags: c#, delegates, instantiation

I have seen different forms of instantiating a delegate object. For example:

I have the following delegate and method.

```
public delegate void Delegate();
public void foo();
```

And these two options for instantiation.

```
Delegate del = new Delegate(foo);
Delegate del = foo;
```

My question is as follows: What is the semantic difference between these two statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is none.

The long answer is, they both compile to the same IL.

```
Delegate del1 = foo;
Delegate del2 = new Delegate(foo);
```

compiles to

```
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldftn       UserQuery.foo
IL_0008:  newobj      UserQuery+Delegate..ctor
IL_000D:  stloc.0     // del1
IL_000E:  ldarg.0     
IL_000F:  ldftn       UserQuery.foo
IL_0015:  newobj      UserQuery+Delegate..ctor
IL_001A:  stloc.1     // del2
```

Comment: @RihardMarius There are plenty of tools. You can instruct the C# compiler to dump it out - or get a tool like ILSpy, Dotpeek, Reflector, etc.

Comment: @RihardMarius I used LinqPad.  It's an awesome tool for quickly prototyping and running C# code snippets.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely nothing. The compiler will convert the second one into an instantiation of `Delegate` just like the first one:

```
// Delegate del = new Delegate(foo);
ldftn    void App.Program::foo()
newobj   instance void App.Program/Delegate::.ctor(object, native int)
stloc.0

// Delegate de2l = foo;
ldftn    void App.Program::foo()
newobj   instance void App.Program/Delegate::.ctor(object, native int)
stloc.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to my knowledge. The compiler will generate the new for you.
A similar question was [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735159/why-use-new-delegatetypedelegate). This shortcut method was introduced from C# 2.0 onwards - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173176%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: thank you for the link, I swear I did a search and didn't found anything close to my question.