# What is the differencies between AddDelegate addDelegate = new AddDelegate(Add); and AddDelegate addDelegate = Add;

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm a newbie in .net.

I saw some videos about `delegate` in youtube.

someone uses delegate like

```
 AddDelegate addDelegate = new AddDelegate(Add);
```

someone uses delegate like

```
 AddDelegate addDelegate = Add;
```

I've tested 2 ways and I wasn't able to find differences between them.

I want to know what is the differencies between them.

Comment: https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpHEnACmANmQOYCGALmegJYB296AgsMACKU0GZABRsOADwCUAbmSESXHvyp1G6WkoGqmAXnSsyAd0V8tQ4d2Az5JS8sFqNplUJjo9l2UgXoADgCdmADchTDgANhZ2E1FoqRtiAm8fInoAC38Ae2MDYwA5TPoASQBbXyoSsnYyYABRcQBjMl96ZkzWYWtkkgBfBLRMABZ0AFlO/AS+pB6gA

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735159/why-use-new-delegatetypedelegate

Comment: It's like asking what the difference is between `Person p = new Person(); var q = new Person(); Person r = new();`

Comment: They're literally identical; see linked question for a lot more context