# What is the difference between new Thread(void Target()) and new Thread(new ThreadStart(void Target()))?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I would like a concise answer on the differences between the following two usages. VS seems to accept both of them as valid code.

```
private static void doSomeWork()
{
   //do some work
}

public someClass()
{
   //Thread thread = new Thread(doSomeWork);
   //or
   //Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(doSomeWork));
}
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360555/how-to-pass-parameters-to-threadstart-method-in-thread

Comment: Very similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749868/new-eventhandlermethod-vs-method

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Delegate Instantiation vs. Just Passing the Method Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181282/c-sharp-delegate-instantiation-vs-just-passing-the-method-reference)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only difference is that the first one doesn't work in C# 1. The compiler of C# 2 and later, translates the first one into the second one.

Method groups are implicitly convertible to delegate types with a compatible signature. This feature is called "(Implicit) method group conversion". Sometimes you need the second one to guide overload resolution, but that's not the case here.